# How to get the IDs of IdentityRoles for which a user is enrolled in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I am trying to get an `IList<ApplicationRole>` of roles in which a user is currently enrolled.

Now in the [`UserManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1) class I see there is a function called [`GetRolesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync), but it just returns a list of role names `IList<String>`. This doesn't help me as I need not only the `Name` property, but also the `Id` and `Description` properties of the roles.

How can I make a similar call but receive an `IList<ApplicationRole>` list of roles back and not an `IList<String>` of role names?

**ApplicationRole**

```cs
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to query the ApplicationDbContext for it as there's no obvious way to get it with a single call from the `UserManager` or `UserStore` APIs...

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var roles = await context.Users
                    .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
                    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles)
                    .Join(context.Roles, ur => ur.RoleId, r => r.Id, (ur, r) => r)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 11):

I think you're looking for `RoleManager`. It's very similar in form and function to `UserManager`, but is specifically intended for CRUD with roles.

```
var RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
```

Where `context` is an instance of your `DbContext`.

Then, you can do:

```
var role = await RoleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
```

Or

```
var role = await RoleManager.FindByNameAsync(roleName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get a list of ApplicationRoles.

```
 List<string> roleNames = UserManager.GetRoles(userId).ToList();

 List<ApplicationRole> roles = RoleManager.Roles.Where(r => roleNames.Contains(r.Name)).ToList();
```